# Appending a new array to a JSON object with SQL Server

Tags: sql, arrays, json, sql-server, sql-server-2019

I would like to append an array to a JSON object:

JSON object:

```js
{ "value1": "test" }
```

Array to be appended:

```js
{ "array2": ["1", "2", "3"] }
```

Expected result:

```js
{ "value1": "test", "array2": ["1", "2", "3"] }
```

My attempts with `JSON_MODIFY` failed:

Attempt #1:

```sql
SELECT 
    JSON_MODIFY('{ "value1": "test" }',
                'append $.array2', 
                JSON_QUERY('[ "1", "2", "3" ]'))

-- { "value1": "test", "array2": [["1", "2", "3"]] }
-- An array within an array is appended
```

Attempt #2:

```sql
SELECT 
    JSON_MODIFY('{ "value1": "test" }',
                'append $',
                JSON_QUERY('{"array2": [ "1", "2", "3" ]}'))

-- { "value1": "test" }
-- Result doesn't contain the array at all
```

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to set a property, not appending items to array so remove the `append` keyword:

```sql
SELECT JSON_MODIFY(
    '{"value1": "test"}',
    '$.array2',
    JSON_QUERY('["1", "2", "3"]')
)
-- {"value1": "test","array2":["1", "2", "3"]}
```